# Guava cache : cacheloader vs get(k,callable)

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am new to Guava cache, I am confused after reading the document
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained.

Whats the difference between using a cacheloader with load method vs using a get method with callable get(K, Callable) to load the key if it doesn't exists in cache.

To me they both serve the same purpose of loading the key. Cant find the diff between two from thew doc. 
can someone please help.

Comment: What did you do to that link?

Comment: I think the difference just depends on how you want to use it. There's no point in instantiating a new Callable every time if it's always the same, so in that case you may as well add a loader. If the method of loading depends on the situation at the site of the 'get' call, then you might want to use the Callable form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main advantage of a `LoadingCache` is that it promotes performing the computation through the cache, rather than a racy get then compute then put approach that is often used instead. It communicates to developers how the cache should be used.

Feature wise a `LoadingCache` provides bulk loading (`getAll`), non-blocking refresh, and a little brevity such as `getUnchecked`. A refresh may be performed explicitly through `refresh(key)` or implicitly using `refreshAfterWrite` during the build phase.

When the computation is complex then its nice to move the logic into its own class. By extending a `CacheLoader` instead of a `Callable` it communicates the intent a little better.

Performance wise there isn't a big difference. The `get(key, callable)` internally creates a decorator `CacheLoader` on every invocation that adapts to a `load`, so there is an eden space object created.

In my Java 8 rewrite, [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), there are some additional options. An `AsyncLoadingCache` provides a similar API but returns a `CompletableFuture`. If you require more direct control, the new `Map` compute methods are supported as atomic operations.

In general prefer to use a `LoadingCache` for its communicative properties to the rest of your team. Everything else is gravy.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted all of your values to be constantly computed using the same method, using a `CacheLoader` might be a better idea.

If, say, you have a caching method that creates new instances of separate implementations of a class, and you don't want to use a `switch` or `if` chain, you would use `get(Object, Callable)`.

You should use the loading method preferably because it doesn't require instantiation of a new `Callable` each `get`.